# Как превратить подобный кусок html в json, а затем обратно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такой кусок html:

```
<div class="card mb-5 type-A"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button><div class="card-body"><div class="form-group"><h4>Тестовый заголовок вопроса</h4></div><div class="form-group"><p>Первый вариант ответа</p></div><div class="form-group"><p>Второй вариант ответа</p></div><div class="form-group"><p>Третий вариант ответа</p></div><div class="form-group"><p>Четвёртый вариант ответа</p></div></div></div>
```

Он образуется после того, как я изменяю `textarea` на элемента `h4` и `p`, но теперь мне надо это отправить в базу данных. Таких кусков в одной ячейке может быть очень много, и у меня появился вопрос, можно ли так хранить html в ячейке базы, или нужно это преобразовывать в json? И как это сделать так, чтобы потом можно было это преобразовать обратно в html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это чтобы удобнее было смотреть :)

```
<div class="card mb-5 type-A">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Тестовый заголовок вопроса</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Первый вариант ответа</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Второй вариант ответа</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Третий вариант ответа</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Четвёртый вариант ответа</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

А что вы хотите вообще от json и для чего?

Если хотите, чтобы этот код формировался с помощью jquery автоматически, то достаточно хранить только варианты ответа, что-то типа

```
data = {
    question: Тестовый заголовок вопрос,
    answers: [
        Первый вариант ответа,
        Второй вариант ответа,
        Третий вариант ответа,
        Четвертый вариант ответа,
    ]
};
```

И из этой записи генерировать html код,

Comment: извиняюсь, чёт не додумался :)

Comment: сразу по json копать начал, просто не хотелось загромождать ячейки в базе